# unable to set a background image to hero-unit in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

how ever i try to set a background image to the hero-unit in bootstrap it just turns up blank,
it displays the body color, i tried setting the z-index value also, it just doesnt work, this is my first time designing a web page and i am all out of ideas

here is the code, plz guide..

```
.hero-unit {
  padding: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-image:url('img/tech9.jpg');
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
        border-radius: 6px; 
}
```

and yes i have double checked my image path and the file name....

Comment: Can you check your browser's *Net* console tab and make sure the `img/tech9.jpg` is actually loading correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your css is in an external file like style.css and your image is not in the same folder

like this

```
css/

   style.css

img/

     tech9.jpg

index.html
```

then your image url should be like

```
    background-image:url('../img/tech9.jpg');
```